# Possible to write an implement of RAIDZ or RAIDZ2 for the MD driver in the Linux kernel?

Tags: performance, raid, linux-kernel, raidz

I am curious on if it is possible to have an implement of RAIDZ and/or RAIDZ2 in the MD driver in the Linux kernel?

From my understanding of it is that the RAIDZ version is equivalent to a RAID 5, and that a RAIDZ2 is equivalent to a RAID 6.

The main difference is that the stripe size can be variable for RAIDZ as opposite to RAID 5/6 from my understanding, which helps performance.

So what I am wondering is would it be possible to add this performance enhancing technique to RAID 5 & 6 in the MD driver in the kernel? Or is it tied too closely to how the ZFS works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read Jeff Bonwick's blog on [RAID-Z](https://blogs.oracle.com/bonwick/entry/raid_z)?

In it he focuses on how RAID-Z is a solution to the RAID-5 write hole problem and explicitly mention that reconstructing a RAID-Z array is closely tied to ZFS and its meta data.

Comment: Doh! I had a feeling that i was missing something when i made the question, thanks!